# What tools are there to connect a Bluetooth speaker to my PC?

Tags: bluetooth, speakers

I have several Bluetooth speakers I can use on my smartphone but I'm wondering if there is any way to connect them via Bluetooth to my PC?  I thought there may be a gadget out there which connects my smartphone to my PC or maybe even some software which makes this connection.

Maybe there's a special dongle I need?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding, you want to connect a bluetooth speaker to your PC, correct?

Comment: Do check whether you have integrated Bluetooth first, though. It can sometimes be hard to find, but it would be really annoying to buy a separate Bluetooth dongle only to discover you didn't need it.

Comment: Do the speakers have an audio-in plug? Looks similar to a headphones one

Answer (score 4):

You need a small dongle that adds Bluetooth capability to your computer. I recommend something small like the [AZiO Micro Bluetooth Adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833340012). This device is under $15 on Newegg.

[image: AZiO Bluetooth]

This device plugs into a USB port and enables Bluetooth communications with various devices via Bluetooth (speakers, printers, keyboards/mice, phones, and more).

After installation of the drivers, you will perform standard Bluetooth device pairing to get your speakers to communicate with the newly enabled dongle.

Comment: Hi.   Yes I am trying to make a bluetooth speaker connect to my computer.  The speaker has bluetooth capability but it only connects to my smartphone (Motorola or samsung or any other smartphone) but not my Personal Desktop Computer.     I am already using a bluetooth Dongle like the one shown above.  While it sometimes does detect the speaker it provides no functionality to the speaker.

Comment: @Svetsi, if that is your question, this is off topic for Hardware Recommendations. We don't provide technical support for hardware issues. I have it on decent authority that this type of support would be on topic on [Super User](http://superuser.com). However, you need to clarify your question. I didn't take your original question as a technical support question.

Comment: @Svetsi In order for this question to be a high quality question on SU, you must state what you have tried to fix the issue yourself. This could be Google searches, tweaking settings, etc. You also have to word is as a problem, not as a recommendation. Let me know if you have any questions about asking on SU.

Comment: Clearly I have googled this to death.  I am asking if there is something available, maybe  a special dongle which mimics the Bluetooth on a mobile phone but used on a PC.   This is a very good question because if it is solvable many people will take something from it's answer. I am not looking for technical support at all.  That is something you have derived from my question.  As mentioned, there must be a device which enables a connection for devices (normally meant for a phone) which can be connect that device to a PC.  Does such a device exist as thousands of searches leaves me with nothing

Comment: To add to this, Andy has tried to help by providing a Bluetooth Dongle.  As I have stated, I have tried this.  I'm thinking that this matter will require no ordinary dongle.  My Dongle supports Bluetooth 2.0.  Should be enough.